# Store nested key names in variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary `foo` that might contain 0..x number of keys with some of those keys being nested. I have a list of keys for which, if they are present in `foo`, I would like to add their values to a different dictionary, `bar`, using different key names. As I can't know whether each key is present in `foo`, I need to check whether they are present in the dict and assign the value in `bar` as `None` if they don't exist. For example:

```
foo = {"ex1": "1",
       "ex2": "2",
       "ex3": {"ex3nest": "3"},
       "ex4": "4",
       "ex5": "5"}

field_mappings = {"bar1": "ex1",
                  "bar2": "ex2",
                  "bar4": "ex4"}

bar = {}
for key, value in field_mappings.items():
    bar[key] = foo[value] if value in foo else None
```

The value of bar will correctly be:

```
{"bar1": "1", "bar2": "2", "bar4": "4"}
```

However, I would like to add a key to `bar` that contains the value of the nested `ex3nest` key, e.g:

```
field_mappings = {"bar1": "ex1",
                  "bar2": "ex2",
                  "bar3": key for ex3nest here,
                  "bar4": "ex4"}
```

I can't see any value that I can assign to the `bar3` key to plug into `value` in the loop in order to the value for `ex3nest`. Is there a way to store a nested key name within a string as I'm trying to do or is my approach here completely wrong to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's a better approach, but I would use `ex3.ex3nest` style as key (borrowed style from js objects).

```py
foo = {
    "ex1": "1",
    "ex2": "2",
    "ex3": {
        "ex3nest": "3"
    },
    "ex4": "4",
    "ex5": "5",
    "ex6": {
        "ex6nest1": {
            "ex6nest2": "6"
        }
    },
    "ex8": {
        "ex8nest1": {
            "ex8nest2": "8"
        }
    },
}

field_mappings = {
    "bar1": "ex1",
    "bar2": "ex2",
    "bar3": "ex3.ex3nest",
    "bar4": "ex4",
    "bar5": "ex5",
    "bar6": "ex6.ex6nest1.ex6nest2", # 2 levels deep
    "bar7": "ex7", # doesn't exists
    "bar8": "ex8.INVALID_KEY", # oops!
}

bar = {}
for key, value in field_mappings.items():
    nested_keys = value.split(".")
    
    bar_value = foo
    for curr_key in nested_keys:
        bar_value = bar_value.get(curr_key, None)
        
        if bar_value is None:
            break

    bar[key] = bar_value

print(bar)
```

which outputs,

```py
{'bar1': '1', 'bar2': '2', 'bar3': '3', 'bar4': '4', 'bar5': '5', 'bar6': '6', 'bar7': None, 'bar8': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey if I understand the question correctly, you can use this code, assuming you have one key in nested dict:

```
foo = {"ex1": "1",
   "ex2": "2",
   "ex3": {"ex3nest": "3"},
   "ex4": "4",
   "ex5": "5"}

field_mappings = {"bar1": "ex1",
                  "bar2": "ex2",
                  "bar3": "ex3",
                  "bar4": "ex4"}

bar = {}
for key, value in field_mappings.items():
    if value in foo:
        if type(foo[value])==type({}):
            bar[key] = foo[value].keys()[0]
        else:
            bar[key] = foo[value]
   else:
       bar[key] = None
```

[image]

or this one if you have multiple keys in the nested dict:

```
bar = {}
for key, value in field_mappings.items():
    if value in foo:
        if type(foo[value])==type({}):
            bar[key] = ",".join(foo[value].keys())
        else:
            bar[key] = foo[value]
     else:
        bar[key] = None
```

[image]